# Access variable which lies inside for-loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have got a for loop, but can't access variable from outside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0; i < [array1 count] && j < [array2 count] && k < [array3 count] && l < [array4 count]; i++ && j++ && k++ && l++)
{

    NSDictionary *_myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[array1 objectAtIndex:i], @"Apples", [array2 objectAtIndex:j], @"Oranges", [array3 objectAtIndex:k], @"Grapes", [array4 objectAtIndex:l], @"Plums", nil];


}
```

Accessing it from inside works.

I tried it with singleton and instance method, it is still not accessible and always returns nil.

I would love to have global variable of it, but can't declare it inside the loop.

Comment: Which variable are you trying to access?

Comment: thanks for quick reply, am trying to access the entire dictionary _myDict.

Comment: declare it outside the for loop? can that help you?

Comment: I have tried NSDictionary *_myDict = @"My Dictionary"; before the loop, but that returns only that same string.

Comment: In my header file I declared it: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *_myDict;  After i declared it before loop, changing it from non-atomic to atomic, it transformed it, but returned (null) still.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith The loop you posted just reassigns new dictionary to `_myDict` in each iteration (no matter where `_myDict` is declared). If you want to collect values into single dictionary, adapt code from the answer below.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith And `i++ && j++ && k++ && l++` really should be `i++, j++, k++, l++`, unless you intentionally prevent increment of `j`, `k` and `l` after first iteration.

Comment: Please read up on variable types ('I declared NSDictionary *myDict = @"my dictionary"'), properties in general, memory management and variable scope. And that loop is from hell, isn't it? You could do what you're doing with just one iterator provided the i++ && j++ && k++ && l++ is unintentional, like @Artur pointed out

Comment: @Mario it really came from hell, but I created a marvel gem of application with it, and I can't get around the loop, it uses NSPipe with launch paths etc., anything else would make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0;
     i < [array1 count] && j < [array2 count] && k < [array3 count] && l < [array4 count];
     i++, j++, k++, l++)
{
     NSMutableDictionary *row = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     [row setObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Apples"];
     [row setObject:[array2 objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"Oranges"];
     [row setObject:[array3 objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"Grapes"];
     [row setObject:[array4 objectAtIndex:l] forKey:@"Plums"];
     [rows addObject:row];
}
```

Now connect your `arrayController` to `rows` array, set it's row class to NSMutableDictionary, and use @"Apples" etc in column bindings. Hope that solves it.

Comment: I want to use NSPredicate on it, and I am using bindings, but I can only do that with the filtered results, once I can access the dictionary...

Comment: and I am filling my NSTableView successfully, but not so with the filtered results, since the NSMutableDictionary _myDict is empty already before any filtering.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith With `rows` array at hand, you can apply `NSPredicate` with `[rows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]`. Or set predicate to `arrayController`, whatever you need.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith Look, dictionary just represents one row. It is meaningless to apply predicate on it. You apply predicate to array of rows, to filter them out. If you use cocoa bindings, then bind `arrayController.contentArray` to `rows`, bind table columns to `arrayController.arrangedObjects.<apples-whatever>`, bind `arrayController.filterPredicate` to your predicate object and that's it.

Comment: PERFECT! This works like a charm! Thanks so much! (I wish I could vote the answer officially, but I still do here like this!)

Comment: in your code you meant to use objectAtIndex:i..j..k..l etc., that works.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith Oh, yes, I forgot to change them. And you may return to your original `[NSDictionary dictionaryWith...]` statement, if you do not need mutability of row cells. Just do not forget to add resulting `row` to `rows`.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith Wait, they are all the same :) Drop `j,k,l` -- just use `i`.

Comment: not the same, got uncaught exception when using just "i" for all: *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 176 beyond bounds [0 .. 175]

Comment: @JeremiahSmith It is very strange. All 4 variables are incremented by one each time, until you are out of elements in the smallest of all arrays -- and loop ends. I don't touch black magic anyway :)

Comment: The loop should be: `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < array1.count && i < array2.count && i < array3.count && i < array4.count; i++)`. No need for 4 variables. Even better - calculate the minimum count of the 4 arrays before the loop then use that value in the loop condition instead of check all 4 arrays every iteration.